# How to fix react rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, optimization

I am building a chat application and I am making the UI, I am stuck on a problem in the actual chat section where when you scroll to see messages not in view, they don't render until you select them with your mouse.

The message component

```
interface Props {
    message: string;
    img: string;
    sender: string;
}

const Message = (props: Props) => {
    if (props.sender == "away") {
        return (
            <div className="message away">
                <img src={props.img} className="sender" alt="sender" />
                <span>{props.message}</span>
            </div>
        );
    } else if (props.sender == "home") {
        return (
            <div className="message home">
                <img src={props.img} className="sender" alt="sender" />
                <span>{props.message}</span>
            </div>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <p>Error in handling</p>
        )
    }
};

export default Message;
```

The component for handling messages

```
import Message from './Message'

const Messages = () => {
  return (
        <div className="messages">
            <Message
                message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquam purus vel pretium malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed interdum at leo nec lobortis. Donec nec lobortis magna. Vivamus ante est, pulvinar ut est eget, tempor egestas leo. Suspendisse non libero ac nisl laoreet volutpat. Praesent faucibus quam at egestas accumsan. Fusce et urna sit amet leo laoreet vehicula sed et enim. Aliquam consectetur justo et nibh ultricies scelerisque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ultricies pretium augue ac tempor. In id laoreet lectus, gravida ornare nisi."
                img="data:image/png;base64,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"
                sender="away"
            />
            <Message
                message="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris aliquam purus vel pretium malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed interdum at leo nec lobortis. Donec nec lobortis magna. Vivamus ante est, pulvinar ut est eget, tempor egestas leo. Suspendisse non libero ac nisl laoreet volutpat. Praesent faucibus quam at egestas accumsan. Fusce et urna sit amet leo laoreet vehicula sed et enim. Aliquam consectetur justo et nibh ultricies scelerisque. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ultricies pretium augue ac tempor. In id laoreet lectus, gravida ornare nisi."
                img="data:image/png;base64,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"
                sender="home"
            />
        </div>
  );
}

export default Messages
```